# Windows 7 system resource as folder name

Tags: windows-7, shell, windows-explorer

I hope it is not a stupid question, but is it possible to set a folder name to a system32.dll localised string resource? I can set the icon easily on the properties window (eg. from imageres.dll), but I need to set the name also as a resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this easily by editing the **desktop.ini** file for the folder:

```
[.ShellClassInfo]
LocalizedResourceName=@%SystemRoot%\System32\Shell32.dll,-21798
IconResource=%SystemRoot%\System32\Shell32.dll,-184
```